# pyarg_parsetuple crashes python

Tags: python, pyd

I'm trying to parse a boolean and an optional unicode string (which should be set only if the boolean is True).

`PyObject *pBool, *pStr;`

`PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "O!|u", &PyBool_Type, pBool, pStr);`

When I call my function like that:
`func(True, u'str');`
`func(False);`

My code crashes.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the first argument to [`PyArg_ParseTuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/arg.html#c.PyArg_ParseTuple) is `PyObject *args`?

Comment: Yes, but it's not the issue.

Comment: Do you get a stack trace?

Comment: Shouldn't there be the *addresses* of `pBool` & `pStr`? Can you show their declarations otherwise?

Comment: That may be the problem: you'll still need the address of the `PyObject *`s. So keep the same declaration, but use the address-of operator in `PyArg_ParseTuple` for `pBool` and `pStr`.

Comment: You may also want to set a default for `pStr`, since it's optional.